# Add new line to dynamically created js file

Tags: javascript

I am using PHP to concatenate several Javascript files into one.  I need to add new lines beforeeach part is added and have tried '\n' but this throws an unknown character error.  What is the correct character to indicate a new line?

```
file_put_contents($JSfile," /n ");


$jspart = file_get_contents($myfile);
file_put_contents($JSfile,'  '. $jspart  , FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: What's your code? And I don't think this is JS related while more PHP related

Comment: added code. Note, when the outputted file is used, it is being added inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the predefined PHP Constant `PHP_EOL` to add the correct 'End Of Line' symbol:

```
file_put_contents($JSfile, PHP_EOL);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use only following in your Codes**

```
$jspart = file_get_contents($myfile);
file_put_contents($JSfile, $jspart . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```